What is the correct translation for 策定フレーズ?
Japanese Text:
現状の5Gを取り巻く動きとしては、5G用周波数の割当て後に関連サービスを展開する事業者による「セルラー5G」の取組みと、2019年に策定予定の3GPPによる5Gに関する詳細仕様の「策定フレーズ」の2本柱といえる。
My Issue:
I have translated "策定フレーズ" as "formulation phase". But I am still confused about whether it should be the "formulation phase" or the "planning phase".
My understanding:
The current movements surrounding 5G can be divided into two main pillars: the "Cellular 5G" initiatives by service providers who will deploy related services after the allocation of 5G frequencies, and the "formulation phase" of detailed 5G specifications by 3GPP, which is scheduled to be established in 2019.

Wasn't it フェーズ instead of フレーズ?

@aguijonazo No it is not. Thank you for attempting to answer this question.

Then it must be a typo.

Here is the answer I found "translation of "策定フレーズ" as "formulation phase" is accurate and appropriate. The term "策定" generally means formulation, drafting, or development of plans or specifications, while "フレーズ" likely refers to "phase" in this context, indicating a specific stage in a process.
However, the term "planning phase" could also be considered, as it similarly refers to the period during which plans and specifications are being developed. Both terms can be used interchangeably in many contexts, but here are the nuances that might help you decide:"
